# How to remove dublicate values using codeigniter and ajax?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I return passports from my database when I select user using codeigniter and I'm getting these data using ajax.

This is my php code in the controller:

```
public function contactsPassports(){
        // POST data
        $this->load->model('contacts/contacts_international_pass_m');
        $data = $this->input->post();
        $passports = array();
        $where = array('contact_id'=>$data['selected_id']);
        $passports = $this->contacts_international_pass_m->where($where)->order_by('id','DESC')->get_all();
        
        if(!empty($passports)) {
            foreach($passports as $item)
            {
                $item->pass = $this->contacts_international_pass_m->get($item->nat_passport_num);               
            }
        }
        $this->data->passports = $passports;
        echo json_encode($this->data);
    }
```

And this is my ajax code:

```
        $.ajax({
            url:'/companies/ajax/contactsPassports',
            method: 'post',
            data: {"selected_id": contactID},
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            success: function(data){
                var html = '';
                $.each(data.passports, function(key, value) {  
                    console.log(data);                            
                    html += '<div class="nationality_name" style="float:left">'+ value.nat_passport_num + '</div>' + '<div class="nationality_name_delimiter" style="float:left">'+', '+'</div>';    
                });   
                $('#passport').html(html);                   
            }
        });
```

But I want to remove the dublicate passports for every user. For example now I am getting this:

User 1

```
12345678, 1234, 1234, 123456, 123456
```

And I want to getting this:

User 1

```
12345678, 1234, 123456
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [distinct](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=distinct#CI_DB_query_builder::distinct) query builder to select only distinct values:

```
$passports = $this->contacts_international_pass_m->distinct()->select('nat_passport_num')->where($where)->order_by('id','DESC')->get_all();
```